# Determine $\int_{\partial D+}Re(z) \thinspace \mathrm dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the following integral.

$$\int_{\partial D+}Re(z) \thinspace\mathrm dz $$

I have no clue about what $D+$ is in the instructions, although I have seen the same notation in the general proof of the Green Theorem when the frontier (border) is not connected (disconnected) when I divide ${\partial D}$ into two curves ${\partial D+}$ and ${\partial D-}$. Nevertheless I suppose it won't be necessary.

Thanks in advance.

-Alberto

Comment: In my PDE class, when we discussed hyperbolic problems, we used $\Gamma^+$ to represent the positively oriented normal vector to the boundary $\Gamma$. There may be a similar thing going on here.

Comment: It is very necessary to know what $D$ is.